# Natural selection and the Galapagos Islands

Tags: evolution

Woodpeckers found on the South American mainland are able to peck insects from the bark of trees. Would the woodpecker finch have been able to survive if woodpeckers had found their way to the Galapagos Islands where this finch is found?

Comment: Dunno, depends on who eats more. Perhaps both would have diversified into different species or one of the two would have gone extinct, or both or whatever. We have no way of knowing what _would have_ happened.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I think it's too hypothetical for the SO format of questions and answers.  Invasive species can and do happen, even without human intervention, but it would be entirely speculative to try and model how a habitat invasion would play out here.